# How to register local domain name?

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosts-file

I am using **ampps** server to develop a **wordpress** site. I have less storage on my **pc** so I started looking for a good **cds(content delivery system)**. I downloaded cloud flare plugin and tried to make account on cloud flare but when I added my domain which I have created in **hosts** file it says that this is not a **registered domian**.[1](http://cheersbin.com)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Go1c.png)

Comment: this site is not a substitute for google, if you google anything close to domain you will see a lot of sellers..a lot of them..

Comment: @David he already has a domain name, I believe this question is asking how to host on cloudflare - though this isn't an option I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosts file is for redirecting web addresses on your own computer. If you add a domain name in your computer hosts file, it tells to ONLY your own computer, that if you want to go to this given address, then it should be turning back to your own computer (127.0.0.1 for localhost) and not search it from internet. Try to change the "127.0.0.1" on that line of the hosts file to "stackoverflow.com", save the file and see what I mean. It should now redirect your given address to stackoverflow. Don't forget to change it again later or it will be redirected forever.

Registering your domain means that you pay for it and you get the right to use it temporary e.g. the term 'reservation'. If you buy your domain name from a certified registrar company, then you also have to validate your contact data etc. Different top level domains (.com .net .co.uk .eu etc.) are operated by different countries and they all have different regulations, expiration dates and prices. Forinstance today (january 2016) you can buy a .net domain for a year for around 10€. There are also some free registrars (.tk .me) but they have bad reputation and are not that easy to remember for your customers. Also some countries forbid certain content (porn forinstance)

It is convenient to get your domain reservation from where you will be hosting it. Then you don't have to transfer it and do all kinds of quite difficult stuff. You can also have discounts with bundles. Just look for a major registrar, search from Google or Bing or etc. for "domain registrar and web hosting"

Also I suggest you to search Youtube for videos about how to make your first website. Don't get me wrong, I know that you can make the page, but these videos usually include all about domain name buying and website hosting. Some videos also offer their own affiliate code with certain registrars so that if you type the given code in, you get some percentage off the service fee, maybe even a free domain name reservation for a year.

Never give out your planned domain name publicly before you have reserved it to your name. Someone else might be registering it before you with purpose to to sell it to you with higher price later. Also remember that you have to renew your domain reservation periodically, usually once a year. Good luck with your site!